# CSRF verification failed. when using cURL

Tags: php, curl

i'm trying to get content of `markafoni.com` by curl.

```
class curl
{
    private $ch;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO,dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        //curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);//
        //curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.markafoni.com/');//
        //curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);//
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
        //curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
        //curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie.txt");
    }

    function run($url,$post=array())
    {
        $postField = '';
        foreach($post as $k=>$v) $postField .= $k.'='.$v.'&';

        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        if(count($post)){
            curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($post));
            curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postField);
        }else{
            curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_POST,0);
            curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'');
        }
        return curl_exec($this->ch);
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a 'Referer header' to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent. This header is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

If you have configured your browser to disable 'Referer' headers, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for HTTPS connections, or for 'same-origin' requests
```

any idea?

## edit:

and when I enable this line:

`curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,'https://www.markafoni.com/');`

I get another error:

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

Comment: Don't you get any idea from those 4 lines of error?

Comment: a useful idea. I fixed that with CURLOPT_REFERER but the site stil recognize me as a robot

Comment: @Pooya that's because they don't want people to be doing what you're doing.

Comment: but I khow there is a solution with cURL. because the browser are doing this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser will always make a get request to a page (to show the form) before making the post.

Consider the following response headers from a get request made from chrome:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 29 May 2014 11:57:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Cookie
CACHE: True
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=5F3ttzJcnWdLkL7sPDekggxgjDJTKAmz; expires=Thu, 28-May-2015 11:57:01 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie: _auth=0; Domain=.markafoni.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: ladsrv=; Domain=.markafoni.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Path=/
X-BackendID: caramel
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Content-Encoding: gzip
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR LAW CURa ADMa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR DELa BUS IND PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV INT STA",policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml"
```

Notice the cookies set, specifically this one: `csrftoken=...`.

In order to make post requests to this site, you will need to make a get request 1st, save the cookies, then make the post request with the same cookies.